# React method not being called on click when used in arrow function

Tags: reactjs, function

So I am having a problem with calling a React method that I am receiving in props.

This is my code

```
   render() {
    const {    
        handleDeleteItem,
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <Fragment>
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={() => handleDeleteItem(2)}>
                        <DeleteForeverIcon />
                    </IconButton>
        </Fragment>
     )};
```

But it's working when I use it like this

```
onClick={handleDeleteItem(2)}
```

I am using class components and the main thing that I am trying to achieve is to call 2 functions on that button click as such as one method is from props and the other is a simple one *(console.log or something)*

Comment: Can you expand this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the parent definition of `handleDeleteItem` you almost certainly have the function as a double `return`

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
    const {    
        handleDeleteItem,
    } = this.props;
        handleDeleteItem(2)()
        console.log('I have been clicked')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <IconButton
                    onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <DeleteForeverIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

If you make it `onClick={() => handleDeleteItem(2)}>`, then that extra anon function is making it a triple return. When invoking it as  `handleDeleteItem(2)`, it is already a function.

For your second question, you just need to invoke it one more time if you are not going to run `handleDeleteItem` in your `onClick` callback event listener

Comment: The way that's working it's good. I don't want to mess with it. I only want to add extra method on that  onClick={handleDeleteItem(2)} since right now it's like this

Comment: @NatyraBlakaj I see. I didn't see your follow up question. I thought this was just a question about a bug. I will update.

Comment: It won't work because handleDeleteItem is from props, even if I try this.props.handleDeleteItem it doesn't work.

Comment: Something else is wrong if `this.props.handleDeleteItem` isn't working. `this.props` is available in any method of your component. Are you sure you are invoking it twice like in my code snippet?